# Ir a la parte superior del html5 con Angular6

Tags: html, angular

Debajo del formulario tengo un botón que se accede haciendo scroll (el formulario es muy grande).

Quiero que al darle al botón de guardar o cancelar, la vista del html vuelva arriba de la página.

He probado con:

**EDITO**:

```
import { Inject} from "@angular/core";
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

 constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document, ...

 public save = function() {


    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
    document.body.scrollTop = 0 ;
    this.document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    this.document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
    this.document.body.scrollTop = 0 ;
    window.scroll({
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        behavior: 'smooth',
      });
   window.scroll(0, 0);
  .
  .
  .
```

No consigo hacer que suba arriba del todo.

```
        <form #annotations="ngForm" (ngSubmit)=save()>
            <div class="row">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>

                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <ng-container *ngIf="indGrupo1">
                            <tr *ngFor="let data of params1">

                            </tr>
                        </ng-container>
                        <ng-container *ngIf="indGrupo2">

                        </ng-container>
                        <ng-container *ngIf="indGrupo3">

                        </ng-container>
                        <ng-container *ngIf="indGrupo4">

                        </ng-container>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="btn-group btn-primary">
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" name="buttonSave" id="save" [disabled]="annotations.form.pristine || btnSave">Guardar</button>
                        <input type="button" value="Cancelar" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" (click)="cancel()" name="buttonCancel" [disabled]="annotations.form.pristine || btnSave">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

/**
     * Método para guardar los cambios
     */
    public save() {

```
   // this.viewportScroller.scrollToAnchor(elementId);

   //  document.documentElement.href = "#top";
   //  this.document.location.href = "#top";
    window.scroll({
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        behavior: 'smooth',
      });
   window.scroll(0, 0);
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    this.document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    this.document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
    this.document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    // Remueve las alertas
   // this.removeAlert();
```

Comment: ¿Has probado con `window.document.scrollingElement.scrollTop=0`?

Comment: Acabo de probarlo y tampoco funciona.

Comment: ¿Has probado con [`window.scroll(0, 0)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll)? Puedes hacer una transición suave si usas `window.scroll({ top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' })`. La propiedad `left` no es obligatoria, pero así te aseguras que se mostrará la parte superior izquierda como si hubieras recargado la página.

Answer (score 0):

Usa [`window.scroll(0, 0)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll). O bien puedes hacer una transición suave si usas `window.scroll({ top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' })`.

La propiedad `left` no es obligatoria, pero así te aseguras que se mostrará la parte superior izquierda como si hubieras recargado la página.

Tu código quedaría:

```
public save = function() {
  // Remueve las alertas
  this.removeAlert();
  window.scroll({
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth',
  });
}
```

Comment: Lo siento, tampoco funciona, edito el post para añadirlo a la lista de cosas que he probado.

Comment: ¿Podrías publicar tu plantilla o algo que nos dé más pistas? A mí siempre me ha funcionado de esta forma correctamente. He creado un entorno de pruebas para comprobar su correcto funcionamiento: https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-breeze-ernnp

Comment: También nos vendría muy bien que publicaras cualquier mensaje de advertencia o error que aparezca en la consola de javascript. Muchas veces un error de javascript detiene la ejecución del código y evita la ejecución del que estás esperando.

Comment: Ya está el código que me has pedido, estamos mirando y puede ser que el window. o el document que apunta hacía arriba, lo esté interpretando para el componente principal, yo me encuentro en un sub--componente

Comment: He vuelto a reproducir el código usando un subcomponente y por tu respuesta he entendido que tu problema no está para nada relacionado con que sea o no un subomponente, si no por un atributo CSS que tiene un elemento padre.

Comment: flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
tiene el padre

Answer (score -1):

Encontré la solución !

Hice un `console.log(window);` y se vio que las propiedad de Y era 0, por eso no cogía ningún método, porque ya estaba en 0.

Lo que he hecho es coger el div del componente principal y hacerle el top.

```
let main = document.documentElement.querySelector('.content-area')
main.scroll(0, 0);
```

Parece ser que al ser un subComponente de la aplicación ya te marca los valores de Y con 0 (no sé por qué), entonces hay que elegir algún selector del componente principal y hacerle referencia.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: He reproducido el problema agregando un subcomponente a mi entorno de pruebas inicial y el código que propuse sigue funcionando correctamente: https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-breeze-ernnp Por la solución que estás dando entiendo que estás usando un campo padre que tiene el atributo CSS `overflow: scroll` con un alto máximo y lo que quieres es que el scroll de ese campo padre sea el que suba hasta arriba. En ese caso, para evitar que se produzca ese problema en otro campo cualquiera, te recomiendo iterar por todos aquellos que tengan dicho atributo.

Comment: pues no sé porque, porque he hecho lo que me dijiste, además de poner por console los addeventListener de tu código para que se ejecutase por JS y tampoco lo hacía (ni con lo tuyo ni con todo lo que había probado, sólo los alerts para comprobar yo que se estaba haciendo).

Comment: ¿Podrías comprobar si el elemento cuya clase es `content-area` tiene el atributo CSS `overflow: scroll` como he deducido? Esa es la explicación por la que la página aparentemente no subía: lo hacía, estaba ya en la parte superior, pero era el scroll de un elemento hijo el que estaba en una posición que no deseabas.

Comment: flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: auto;

Comment: Pues ahí estaba el problema. No era por ser un subcomponente, es porque era una etiqueta que tenía su propio scroll (te puse `overflow-y: scroll` para forzar aparecer el scroll, pero `overflow: auto` también lo hace aparecer si el contenido supera la altura). Espero que mi explicación te haya ayudado a entender el problema raíz que estabas sufriendo. Un saludo.

Comment: Esto no es una solucion real, es un parche a una mala programacion. saludos.